# How can I ensure my keypress isn't handled before a new element is loaded?

Tags: wpf

I have a child element which focuses the appropriate element within itself on its Loaded event.  We're finding that some quick fingered testers are able to hit the keypress to open the element, and the next keypress goes to the parent instead of the newly focused container!  So the keypress is beating whatever async process WPF runs in order to load the child control.

The target in both the parent and child controls is a simple text box.

Is there a guaranteed way to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: you could try the IsVisibleChanged event instead of Loaded

Comment: I usually use [`DispatcherPriority.Input`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx), however depending on where your keypress events are hooked up to, that may or may not work